# Getting not found and bad substitution error

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell

Here is my script code to find when user enters n numbers to find whether numbers are odd or even, but I guess my arrays are not working

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Enter the value of n:"
read n
e=0
o=0
while [ $n -gt 0 ]
do
    echo "Enter the number:"
    read a
    t=`expr $a % 2`
    if [ $t -eq 0 ]
    then
        even[e]=$a
        e=`expr $e + 1`
    else
        odd[o]=$a
        o=`expr $o + 1`
    fi
    n=`expr $n - 1`
done
echo "The even numbers are ${even[*]}"
echo "The odd numbers are ${odd[*]}"
exit 0
```

I get errors like

```
test.sh: 15: test.sh: odd[o]=1: not found
test.sh: 12: test.sh: even[e]=2: not found
test.sh: 20: test.sh: Bad substitution
```

Where is the error and why does it happen?

Answer (score 2):

You are running your script with `/bin/sh` which simply does not have support for arrays. The `bash` shell, on the other hand, has.

You are also using some somewhat antiquated constructs, such as `expr` for doing arithmetics.

Here's a version of the script written for `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p 'Enter n: ' n

while (( n > 0 ))
do
    read -p 'Enter number: ' a

    if (( a % 2 == 0 ))
    then
        even+=( "$a" )
    else
        odd+=( "$a" )
    fi
    n=$(( n - 1 ))
done

echo "The even numbers are ${even[*]}"
echo "The odd numbers are ${odd[*]}"
```

The major changes include fixing the `#!` line to point to `bash`, using `(( ... ))` for arithmetic evaluation, `$(( ... ))` for arithmetic substitution, `read -p` to give the user a prompt, `+=(...)` to add an element to an array, and removal of unneeded variables.

---

A non-interactive version of the script which takes the numbers from the command line:

```
#!/bin/bash

for number do
    if (( number % 2 == 0 )); then
        even+=( "$number" )
    else
        odd+=( "$number" )
    fi
done

printf 'The even numbers: %s\n' "${even[*]}"
printf 'The odd numbers: %s\n'  "${odd[*]}"
```

Testing:

```
$ bash script.sh 1 2 3 4
The even numbers: 2 4
The odd numbers: 1 3
```

Comment: Gives error: test.sh: 8: test.sh: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

Comment: @SujitMaiti This is because you are still executing the script with `sh` (which may be the `dash` shell on your machine). Either run the script with `bash script.sh` or make sure that the script has a proper `#!`-line pointing to `bash` on your system and that it's executable, then run it as `./script.sh`.

Comment: Yes, the problem is solved now! I ran the script using bash test.sh and it worked :)